# How to exclude directories and files from being pushed to remote repo

Tags: git, gitignore

I have an `Angular` project where I'd like to push only some files into my remote repo via `Git`. Modifying `.gitignore` and using the `.git/info/exclude` didn't work. I'm sure it stopped Git from detecting changes in those places, but these files still got pushed to the remote repo even after creating and pushing a new branch.

How can I exclude, for example, my entire `e2e` folder from being pushed to the remote repo? `node_modules` already behaves this way, as it only exists on my local and wont get comitted to the remote. How do I do that for other files and folders?

Comment: If the files are already tracked by git and *then* you ignored them, they still get tracked. You can remove them from getting tracked with `git rm --cached folderOrFile`.

Comment: @catgirlkelly Does this only take effect for the branch in question, or will this untrack these files for all branches?

Comment: Tracked-ness of a file is a property of Git's *index*. The index is filled in from a commit. The branch name is not relevant: all that matters is what is in the *commit* in question. You will need to make a new *tip commit* in all branches that have a tip commit that contains the files. Note that switching from a commit that contains the files, to one that lacks the files, causes the files to be removed, so while this solution *works* it may have undesired side effects.